# Pyautogui to check if button is enable or disable

Tags: pyautogui

I would like to check if the desktop application button is clickable or not clickable. Is there any way to check this by using [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/)?

I have a button name **Login**, it will be clickable if we provide both **username** and **password** text field.

Comment: you should provide some more information about you question. Well, It is possible to detect it. please provide images of **enabled** and **disabled** button.

Comment: change my original question.  I need to check if the Button is clickable or not. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. you need to have **images of disabled and enabled button**.

Answer (score 0):

This will need the **images of the enabled and disabled button**:
`The images the program wants must be the same resolution.`

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard #pip install keyboard


while True: # I added this loop to make sure that the image will be found.
# Sometimes the image is on the screen but pyautogui cant find it at once so i will make it check it repeatedly for the image.
    
    res_d = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('disabled.png') # capture the image by taking screenshot and cropping it

    if res_d == None:
        print("Enabled")

    
    res_e = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('enabled.png') # capture the image by taking screenshot and cropping it

    if res_e == None:
        print("Disabled")

    if keyboard.is_pressed('q'): # Change this to the logic you want to use for breaking the loop.
        break
```